# adding jquery ui icons to input text forms elements

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, usability

is it possible to simply add icon to input text element ?

i can just add icons to button elements, 
but not to inputs with type text
for example `$(".mybutton").button({icons: {primary:'ui-icon-circle-check'}});`

Comment: quick trick is just add '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-person" style="float:left;margin-top:4px;"></span>' before input